# Defining fmap with id and return

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads, functor

In *Category Theory for Programmers* by Bartosz Milewski, Milewski writes the following code to define return and the 'fish' operator (composition in Kleisli category) for the Writer monad.

```
return :: a -> Writer a
return x = (x, "")

(>=>) :: (a -> Writer b) -> (b -> Writer c) -> (a -> Writer c)
m1 >=> m2 = \x ->
  let (y, s1) = m1 x
      (z, s2) = m2 y
  in  (z, s1 ++ s2)
```

He then proceeds to define `fmap` as follows:

```
fmap f = id >=> (\x -> return (f x))
```

I have difficulties understanding how the `id` function is used here. The first argument to the fish operator clearly is `(a -> Writer b)` but id has the type signature `a -> a`.

Is this an error or a flaw in my understanding? Replacing `id` with `return` makes more sense to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't forget the universal quantifications.

Fish `(>=>)` has type `(a -> Writer b) -> .....` *for any* `a` and `b`.

`id` has type `a -> a` *for any* `a`.

Hence, in particular, fish also has type `(Writer b -> Writer b) -> ...` for any `b` (just take `a = Writer b` as a special case).

Further, `id` has also type `Writer b -> Writer b` (again, as a special case).

The "trick" here is to "merge" the two types using *unification*.
We start by requiring `(a -> Writer b) = (a' -> a')`, and then we infer `a = a'` and `Writer b = a'`. From here, we can see that these two types can be unified, so there is no contradiction in passing the arguments.

(Also note that here we renamed the `a` in the type of `id` to `a'` to avoid confusion with the other `a` for the fish)

Comment: Thank you, that helped. Just an additional question, how does one create such point-free functions? I'm having difficulties thinking about functions without arguments.

Comment: @MohideenImranKhan It's not easy, in the general case. One usually tries specializing the polymorphic values at hand, giving less general types, and then combine them in some way. Also, one can start from a pointful definition, and then use an automatic tool like [this](pointfree.io) to remove the points. Using that tool we rarely get readable code, though.

Comment: @MohideenImranKhan: In general, when writing point-free code, the easiest approach is to break down a problem into many small point-free definitions and combine them with composition or higher-level combinators like `<$>`/`<*>`/`=<<` from the `(->) a` (function/reader) instances of `Functor`, `Applicative`, and `Monad`, or the combinators from `Control.Arrow` like `(&&&)` and `(***)`. You can also start with a pointful function and see if any parts of it match the shape of combinators like `(f . g) x = f (g x)` or `(f <*> g) x` = `f x (g x)`, then incrementally refactor it to be point-free.

Comment: I see. Why do people prefer point-free functions when they make construction and interpretation harder?

Comment: @MohideenImranKhan: In my experience, most experienced Haskellers only use point-free style when it *doesn’t* make constructor or interpretation harder. That usually means sticking to simple pipelines with `(.)`, and using other point-free operators more sparingly—for example, I consider `fmap (f &&& g)` (“get `f` and `g` of each element”) cleaner than `fmap (\x -> (f x, g x))`. A lot of beginners go through a phase where they try to make *everything* point-free—it’s possible, and a good learning exercise, but the language isn’t really designed for it.

Comment: @MohideenImranKhan Point-free is not considered to be a good style in every case. Sometimes it is nice and elegant. However, in many cases it makes the code much harder to read, and it should not be used. When it fails to simplify the code, point-free style is jokingly called "point-less style", since it became a futile exercise. Perhaps the programmer felt clever when reaching a pointfree form, and wants to show it to the world, but showing unreadable code is hardly a good way to show programmer's skills. When you are not sure it simplifies, avoid point-free code.